# Sound problems Ubuntu 16.04 on dell 5470

Tags: sound, 16.04, dell-vostro

I'm a new user on Ubuntu and I have an sound problem when the laptop unplugged:

1. On start-up there some buzzing came from the speakers, with the entering drums.
2. There is some white noise from the speakers and beeping sound on program load like the computer "thinks" (Hard drive working).

What I tried so far

- I checked the microphone and it's not microphone feedback, because when the laptop is plugged everything is OK.
- I updated the ALSA driver but it's still the same.

This is a Dell 5470 i5 4200u SSD drive so there is no moving parts.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that the noises only appear when the computer is *on battery power supply (direct current)* but ***not** on grid power supply (alternating current)*?

Comment: hi David, thanks for the reply!
yes,only when the computer is runing on battery.

Answer (score 0):

I have no concrete solution but you should look into disabling the power management features of

1. the audio chipset,
2. the CPU, and if that doesn't help
3. anything else on-by-one until you find the component/driver that's responsible.

Once you isolated the responsible component you can investigate and decide what to about it. Every attempt to mitigate the issue may increase the power consumption of your system. You're welcome to [open a new question](/questions/ask) with a more concrete request or even intermediate results.

---

Buzzing noises often stem from frequent power level switches somewhere in the system. Power management usually works by switching devices into a lower power state when they're not needed and back to a higher power state when they're needed again. Switching power off and on (or down and up) quickly is also how digital audio adapter devices work. If some of that power switching isn't shielded well enough from the audio hardware and it happens between 16 and ~20,000 times per second this may result in audible buzzing or beeping noises.

Comment: Hi David,
thanks again for your answer.
i will try to check the power management ,hope finding something..
i will post here if there something new..
Good Day !